# Getting a empty row when using "case" (actually its when using an aggregate)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm querying a sqlite database table with my python script.

```
SELECT servername, 
     date('now','localtime'),
     sum(CASE WHEN locked="NO" THEN 1 END),
     sum(CASE WHEN locked="YES" THEN 1 END) 
FROM nodes
WHERE servername="SOME_SERVER"
```

It works ok (giving me the servername, todays date, the number of unlocked nodes, and the number of locked nodes) ...

... except for when there is no match for the query (ie. there is no servername of the name provided).  In that case, the query result is

> null,"2013-04-15",null,null

(I added the nulls for clarity)

It is valid for some servers to have no nodes.  I don't get any query result if I remove the "cases" from the query, so they are causing me to get a result when I don't want one.

How do I make it return nothing in the SQL query, without resorting to detecting it in python, or querying a count beforehand?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm adding a

```
group by servername
```

makes the blank line go away if there is no match, as I accidentally just discovered.  I was having trouble explaining this but I *think* this in the sqlite documentation covers it:

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY
>   clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated
>   once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the
>   result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the
>   dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each
>   non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then
>   each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting
>   entirely of NULL values.
>
> The single row of result-set data created by evaluating the aggregate
>   and non-aggregate expressions in the result-set forms the result of an
>   aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause. **An aggregate query without
>   a GROUP BY clause always returns exactly one row of data, even if
>   there are zero rows of input data.**